# Should SVG really be overlaying this dialog?

Tags: html, css, svg, z-index

an SVG tag is overlaying the following snippet's box, even though it's given less `z-index` than the box.

Snippet:

```css
.nicebox_overlay { width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; display: table; text-align: center; background: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
.nicebox_container { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
.nicebox_content { display: inline-block; text-align: left; background: #EEE; min-height: 250px; min-width: 250px; position: relative; margin: 16px; }
.nicebox_inner_content { z-index: 600; color: white; padding: 8px; box-sizing: border-box; }
.nicebox_svg_tleft { position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; z-index: 1; }
.nicebox_svg_bright { position: absolute; bottom: -10px; right: -10px; transform: rotate(180deg); z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<div class="nicebox_overlay">
            <div class="nicebox_container">
                <div class="nicebox_content">
                    <div class="nicebox_svg_tleft">
                        <svg>
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" width="2px" height="200px" style="fill: #A22;" />
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" height="2px" width="180px" style="fill: #A22;" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nicebox_inner_content">
                        <textarea style="width: 240px; height: 240px">Try and enter something here...</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nicebox_svg_bright">
                        <svg>
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" width="2px" height="200px" style="fill: #A22;" />
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" height="2px" width="180px" style="fill: #A22;" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I just simply want the SVGs to be in the back and the textarea in the snippet to be editable.

Any help is appreciated.

**PS:** I must use `position: static` for the `.nicebox_inner_content` class.

**EDIT:** Using `z-index: -1` works, but it hides the whole SVG element back behind the `body` tag.

**EDIT mkII:** I can also use other `position`s as long as they auto-resize with the inner elements, because this box needs to be flexible.

**EDIT mkIII:** The website: https://www.forcemagic.xyz/_ptExp!542/ The snippet is a simplified and recolored version of the initial site.

Comment: Can you share the UI screenshot what exact you are looking for ?

Comment: I just want to be able to edit that inner textarea, that's all. And also the SVGs to be visible. The UI is the same as in the snippet.

Comment: Okay fine I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adjusted Snippet should meet your requirements, looks same like your initial snippet but textarea is usable.

```css
.nicebox_overlay { width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; display: table; text-align: center; background: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
.nicebox_container { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
.nicebox_content { display: inline-block; text-align: left; background: #EEE; min-height: 250px; min-width: 250px; position: relative; margin: 16px; }
.nicebox_inner_content { z-index: 600; color: white; padding: 8px; box-sizing: border-box; }
.nicebox_svg_tleft { position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; z-index: -1; }
.nicebox_svg_bright { position: absolute; bottom: -10px; right: -10px; transform: rotate(180deg); z-index: -1; }
```

```html
<div class="nicebox_overlay">
            <div class="nicebox_container">
                <div class="nicebox_content">
                    <div class="nicebox_svg_tleft">
                        <svg>
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" width="2px" height="200px" style="fill: #EEE;" />
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" height="2px" width="180px" style="fill: #EEE;" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nicebox_inner_content">
                        <textarea style="width: 240px; height: 240px">Try and enter something here...</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nicebox_svg_bright">
                        <svg>
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" width="2px" height="200px" style="fill: #EEE;" />
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" height="2px" width="180px" style="fill: #EEE;" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's okay, but this snippet in action hides the SVGs. (For me at least) Check out the [original](http://imgur.com/a/qcrwn) and [modified](https://imgur.com/a/T6D71) screenshot from the actual webpage that I want to use this in. (I know, the colors and the content aren't really the same, but believe me, the backbone is the same.

Comment: so you should add full codebase in a fiddle or link the website with the login box. there must be something else as it works in my snippet above when you run it

Comment: I didn't really want to at first, but here it is: https://www.forcemagic.xyz/_ptExp!542/

Comment: okay i see. but why can't you use `position:relative;` on `.nicebox_inner_content` ? it will still be "responsive" / "flexible"

Comment: See edit mkII. As I stated there I can use as long as it's responsive.

Comment: so just use it and everything will be fine

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works amazingly! And as you said, it's still flexible! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding unwanted "z-index" you can simply achieve this:

Just I have added z-index to only two classes.

```
.nicebox_content (
    z-index: 0;
}
.nicebox_inner_content (
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**Here my suggest code:**

```css
.nicebox_overlay { position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;display: table; text-align: center; background: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
.nicebox_container { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
.nicebox_content { display: inline-block; text-align: left; background: #EEE; min-height: 250px; min-width: 250px; position: relative; margin: 16px; z-index:0;}
.nicebox_inner_content { position: absolute; left:0; right:0; top: 15px; color: white; padding: 8px; box-sizing: border-box; z-index:1; }
.nicebox_svg_tleft { position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; }
.nicebox_svg_bright { position: absolute; bottom: -10px; right: -10px; transform: rotate(180deg); }
```

```html
<div class="nicebox_overlay">
 <div class="nicebox_inner_content">
  <textarea style="width: 230px; height: 230px">Try and enter something here...</textarea>
 </div>
 <div class="nicebox_container">
  <div class="nicebox_content">
   <div class="nicebox_svg_tleft">
    <svg>
     <rect x="8px" y="8px" width="2px" height="200px" style="fill: #A22;" />
     <rect x="8px" y="8px" height="2px" width="180px" style="fill: #A22;" />
    </svg>
   </div>
   <div class="nicebox_svg_bright">
    <svg>
     <rect x="8px" y="8px" width="2px" height="200px" style="fill: #A22;" />
     <rect x="8px" y="8px" height="2px" width="180px" style="fill: #A22;" />
    </svg>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where'd the SVGs go?

Comment: But they aren't visible. See my updated snippet. As you can see the SVGs are red, so that people can notice that I want it there :)

Comment: @ForceMagic: Okay fine I updated SVG images you can check it once.

Comment: `position: absolute` is not responsive. The problem has been already solved with `position: relative` (I'm talking about `.nicebox_inner_content` here.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, `pointer-events: none;`

```css
.nicebox_overlay { width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1; display: table; text-align: center; background: rgba(0,0,0,.1); }
.nicebox_container { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
.nicebox_content { display: inline-block; text-align: left; background: #EEE; min-height: 250px; min-width: 250px; position: relative; margin: 16px; }
.nicebox_inner_content { z-index: 600; color: white; padding: 8px; box-sizing: border-box; }
.nicebox_svg_tleft { position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; z-index: 1; pointer-events: none;}
.nicebox_svg_bright { position: absolute; bottom: -10px; right: -10px; transform: rotate(180deg); z-index: 1; pointer-events: none;}
```

```html
<div class="nicebox_overlay">
            <div class="nicebox_container">
                <div class="nicebox_content">
                    <div class="nicebox_svg_tleft">
                        <svg>
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" width="2px" height="200px" style="fill: #A22;" />
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" height="2px" width="180px" style="fill: #A22;" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nicebox_inner_content">
                        <textarea style="width: 240px; height: 240px">Try and enter something here...</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="nicebox_svg_bright">
                        <svg>
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" width="2px" height="200px" style="fill: #A22;" />
                            <rect x="8px" y="8px" height="2px" width="180px" style="fill: #A22;" />
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `pointer-events` should be avoided as it is not cross-browser-compatible

Comment: Actually, it's pretty good CSS property... http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events